# Remove tab/extra spaces on powershell output

Tags: powershell

I've put together a simple script to output a list of computers that are members of AD groups for WSUS Patching.  The problem is that when I use this list of computer names to compare in Excel, there are a load of spaces/tab in the results.  I don't want to have to manually edit the results, so I was wondering if there was a more graceful way to do this within the script?

```
$groups = Get-Content D:\WSUS\grouplist.txt
$result =@()
foreach($group in $groups){$result += Get-ADGroupMember $Group | select name}
$result | Out-File D:\WSUS\WSUS-All-AD-Members.txt
```

I've had a look at other options, but can't seem to get something that works.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, added the -ExpandProperty option....

```
$groups = Get-Content D:\WSUS\grouplist.txt
$result =@()
foreach($group in $groups){$result += Get-ADGroupMember $Group | select -ExpandProperty name}
$result | Out-File D:\WSUS\WSUS-All-AD-Members.txt
```